# Pass a function to a directive and then call it with parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive (show youtube video) that should take a function as an attribute to be able to launch it inside the link function.

Inside the html I wrote (in jade)

```
div(ng-controller="videoPageCtrl")
    ...
    div(my-youtube,id='aaa',url='KEHxHr-Ih9w',on-change="doEventsOnChange")
```

My controller and directive look as following

```
app
.directive('myYoutube', function($sce, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            url: '@',
            id: '@',
            onChange: '&',
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.player = new YT.Player(scope.id, {
                    videoId: scope.url,
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(state) {
                            console.log('state changed to', state, scope.id, scope.onChange);
                            scope.onChange(state, scope.id);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
    };
})
.controller('videoPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $scope.doEventsOnChange = function(state, id) {
        console.log(id, state, 'launched from controller!');
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that I cannot pass `id` and `state` and fire up the `doEventsOnChange` function.
In result in the chrome dev console I can only see the `state changed to` lines, but no `launched from controller!` lines with passed `id` and `state`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onChange: '&'` when you want to use the function in your directive's template, use `onChange: '='` if you just want to pass the function to the directive's scope.

> The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time. Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which contains a function call. Because of this, & bindings are ideal for binding callback functions to directive behaviors.

Comment: So if I had a template in my directive, I should have used `&`?

Comment: If you have a template in your directive and you want to call it from lets say an ng-click there, yes. If you just want to use it in the directive's controller use `=`

Comment: @MartijnWelker .. By creating an isolated scope for the directive, the scope isn't the same. So the directive and the controller aren't using the same scope. By using "=", you're just binding the parent scope's function (model) to a child scope's model :). It will work of course but I think  & would have been more appropriate. And that's because two way binding on a function that will never change (within the controller or directive) is not very appropriate. Using & referencing the function is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you have to use this expression in html

```
div(my-youtube,id='aaa',url='KEHxHr-Ih9w',on-change="doEventsOnChange(state,id)")
```

and in your directive, when passing arguments :

```
console.log('state changed to', state, scope.id, scope.onChange);
scope.onChange({state: state,id:scope.id});
```

See the documentation on [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and the isolate scope definition scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }, the isolate scope property localFn will point to a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope. This can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

Hope this helps.